# Unable to set property of mocked Interface

Tags: c#, properties, rhino-mocks

I have a public interface as follows

```
public interface ICommandUIUpdate
{
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

For unit testing purposes I have mocked the same in the below way

```
var commandUIUpdate = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICommandUIUpdate>();
```

Now , I when I try to set the value of `commandUIUpdate.Enabled = true`, it doesn't work.
It is always set to `false`.

Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `PropertyBehavior` on that property:

```
commandUIUpdate.Stub(x => x.Enabled).PropertyBehavior();
```

Comment: suprisingly when i used var commandUIUpdate = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICommandUIUpdate>(); it all worked fine !

Comment: It would do - `PropertyBehaviour` is the default for stubs, but not for mocks.